# Existe uma palavra maior do que "pneumoultrami..."? Ela é realmente usada?

Tags: vocabulário

No vocabulário temos a palavra *pneumoultramicroscopicossilicovulcanoconiótico* que é o nome dado a uma pessoa que sofre da doença causada pela inspiração de cinzas vulcanicas. Esse termo é realmente usado? Existe uma palavra maior no vocabulário português?

Comment: Essa palavra é totalmente artificial em inglês, e foi trazida pro português de maneira mais artificial ainda.

Comment: Nome de quem sofre com a doença, a doença é **pneumoultramicroscopicossilicovulcanoconiose**

Answer (score 9):

Não existe essa palavra em língua portuguesa. Pelo menos, não no meio médico.  Denominamos "pneumoconiose" as doenças respiratórias causadas pela inalação de poeiras químicas que levam a fibrose pulmonar.  No caso da inalação de cinzas vulcânicas, de forma crônica, pode o indivíduo desenvolver uma pneumoconiose mas não juntaríamos tudo em uma palavra. Especificaríamos a que tipo de pneumoconiose estamos nos referindo.